# All expressions in select and group by but still get error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, group-by

Have a PL/SQL procedure that is taking user input of a movie ID and specific date range, to print out information about the movie based on the ID and the transactions within that date range. I keep getting ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression.

I have looked here for solutions. I keep seeing that the common theme is to include all the expressions in the group by clause that I have in the select clause. To the best of my knowledge, I have done that (maybe I missed something). Any information would be greatly appreciated

```
create or replace PROCEDURE COMPUTE_MOVIE_STATS (MOVIE_ID IN NUMBER, START_DATE IN DATE , END_DATE IN DATE ) AS 

MovieCheckID movies.m_id%type;
Begin
    MovieCheckID := check_movie_id(movie_ID);

    If MovieCheckID >= 1 
    then

select a_seat_capacity, tr_quantity, tr_sum_total, m_title 
  into audit_cap, ticket_num, total_amount, movie_name 
  from showtimes s  
  join auditorium a on a.a_id = s.show_audi_id
  join movies m on m.m_id = s.show_movie_id 
  join transactions t on t.tr_show_id = s.s_id 
 where moviecheckID = movie_id
 group by a_seat_capacity, tr_quantity, tr_sum_total, m_title
having transactions.tr_date between min(start_date) and max(end_date);


  NULL;
END COMPUTE_MOVIE_STATS;
```

Comment: `having` is for conditions at the group level. It seems you want data from the base table (**before** grouping) where the `transaction_date` is between some values. That belongs in a `where` clause. **However**: What are `start_date` and `end_date`? Do you need to group by the same columns you are already grouping by, and get the `MIN` and `MAX` over those additional columns?

Comment: start_date and end_date act as inputs for the user

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  You should write your queries using proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  More importantly, use qualified column names so people know where the columns come from!

Comment: Seems to me your HAVING clause should be added to the WHERE clause.

Comment: If start_date and end_date "act as inputs from the user" then what do you mean by having them wrapped within `min` and `max`? Your question makes less and less sense.

Answer (score 1):

The expressions that can be present in the `HAVING` clause fall in three categories:

1. Columns or expressions you are using to aggregate rows -- that is -- the ones specified in the `GROUP BY` clause.
2. Aggregation functions such as `SUM()`, `MIN()`, `MAX()`, etc.
3. Columns that are directly dependent on the ones from category #1.

In your query, however, the `HAVING` clause includes the expression `transactions.tr_date` that doesn't fall in any of the categories above.

Maybe you can make it fall in category #2 by rephrasing it as `MIN(transactions.tr_date)` or similar.

If that's not the case, then you probably need to rethink your query altogether.